# Solve the torus PDE $2rz u_r + (z^2+1-r^2)u_z = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to arrive at the particular solution

$$u(r,z) = \frac{z^2+r^2+1}{r}$$

for the PDE

$$2rz u_r + (z^2+1-r^2)u_z = 0$$

by the method of characteristics. Setting $r = r(s,t)$ and $z=z(s,t)$, I get a coupled system:

$$\begin{aligned} r_t &= 2rz \\ z_t &= z^2 + 1 - r^2\end{aligned}$$

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you divide both equations you get $$\frac{dz}{dr}+\Big(-\frac{1}{2r}\Big)z=\Big(\frac{1-r^2}{2r}\Big)z^{-1}$$ This is a Bernoulli DE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dz}{dr}=\frac{z^2+1-r^2}{2rz}$$
$$2z\frac{dz}{dr}=\frac{z^2+1-r^2}{r}$$
Let $\quad Z=z^2$
$$\frac{dZ}{dr}-\frac{Z}{r}=\frac{1-r^2}{r} $$
This is a first order lineaer ODE.
$$Z=c\:r-r^2-1$$